# Angular2 beta - bootstrapping HTTP_PROVIDERS - "Unexpected Token <"

Tags: npm, typescript, angular, beta

Starting with the [5 minute quick start](http://a2.hubwiz.com/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) I've been playing around the angular2 beta and have run across a problem that has me stumped.

Here is a dumbed down version that shows the problem I have. First here a hello world app working perfectly.

**package.json**

```
{
   "name": "...",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "description": "...",
   "author": {
   "name": "...",
   "email": "..."
    },
    "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
    },
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.5.10"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^1.3.1",
    "typescript": "^1.7.3"
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js">    </script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>


<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('app/boot')
          .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>

</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
    <my-app></my-app>
</body>
```

**app/boot.ts**

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
import {AccountService} from './accounts/account.service'

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

**app/app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {RegisterFormComponent} from './accounts/register-form.component'
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
})
@View({
    template: 'hello world',
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

I evntually want to call my Web Api service so I am trying to follow [the docs for Http](http://a2.hubwiz.com/docs/js/latest/api/http/Http-class.html), I update boot.ts as follows:

**new app/boot.ts**

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
import {AccountService} from './accounts/account.service'
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

And here's where things choke.

Chrome gives me:

```
uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < - http:1
uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < - angular2-polyfills.js:138
    evaluating http://localhost:3000/angular2/http
    error loading http://localhost:3000/app/boot.js
```

It also fails if I try to set the HTTP_PROVIDERS as a viewProvider on my component.

Has anyone else had any luck getting Http to inject properly in the angular2 beta?

- Visual Studio 2015
- Node.JS & Node.JS tools for visual studio
- Using 'NPM start' to compile and run

Comment: Is this a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34387174 ?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer kind of. In this case he's missing the http bundle, e.g `<script src=".../http.dev.js"></script>`

Comment: Similar error, but a different cause. I have a working app that breaks when I bootstrap HTTP_PROVIDERS. The solution to his problem was to fix the System.Config call in index.html which isn't a problem in my case since everything works perfectly until I bootstrap HTTP_PROVIDERS

Comment: @EricMartinez You're my hero. I was looking at this for ages yesterday and knew that it was something stupid. If you submit an answer I will accept it.

I guess I was hoping that angular would take care of the include for me? What's the point of the import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} statement if it doesn't automatically include the JS? lol :)

Comment: @Cosmosis To answer your question, Angular2 uses the future es6-module importing format. Eventually, browsers *will* support the `import` syntax natively. Until then a polyfill such as system.js is necessary.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This error occurs when you try to import something that is not being included in your HTML when using SystemJS. Module bundlers like Webpack handle all that for you.

For your case you have to add the Http bundle that's a separated bundle, for example

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/http.dev.js"></script>
```

You'll see this same error when trying to use the router and you forgot to add the router bundle.

Check the difference between these two configurations from @pkozlowski-opensource's repos

- [Using SystemJS](https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/ng2-play/blob/master/index.html) : For this case he would've to add http bundle, or router bundle if he wanted to use them.
- [Using Webpack](https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/ng2-webpack-play) : In this case Webpack bundles everything in that `bundle.js` file for you.

Glad it helped.

Comment: I'm finding JSPM is also working well for bundling angular2 modules.

Comment: @brando Unless you want to use it as a separate standalone bundle,  JSPM already provides angular2 `jspm install angular2`.

Comment: Sigh, this error message should be better than this.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using npm, include a script tag with the http reference to your local installation:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as of 3/2016. If anyone else is having this issue, this is the fix.