# Angular2 Http error

Tags: angular

I'm starting learning Angular2 by following the [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) they provide in their page, and now I'm trying to make some [Http requests](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Http-class.html). But whenever I bootstrap the component, Chrome keeps giving me this errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <         http:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <         angular2-polyfills.js:138
   Evaluating http://localhost:3000/angular2/http
   Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/boot.js
```

This is the component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'users',
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  templateUrl: 'app/views/users.html'
})
export class UsersComponent {

  people: Object[];
  constructor(http: Http) {
    http.get('http://192.168.56.101/api/test').subscribe(res => {
      this.people = res.json();
      console.log(this.people);
    });
  }
}
```

And the bootstrapping:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {UsersComponent} from './components/users'

bootstrap(UsersComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

The view is only `{{people}}`.

TypeScript is compiling OK. I don't even know what's failing!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34402203/4933038

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The documentation is lacking on that part. Router and Http need to be added to the index.html. Easy mistake to make

Comment: quick note, the script tags are:  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>

Answer (score 7):

First, if you injected provider on bootstrap, you don't have to do it again in component.

Second, did you included `http.js` in your `index.html`?

And third, you have an error in your code. There should be `this.http.get()` not `http.get()`

Answer (score 1):

in bootstraping you do not have to import the HTTP_PROVIDERS dependencies.
so try:-

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS}    from 'angular2/http';
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {UsersComponent} from './components/users'

bootstrap(UsersComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

and in index file you need to add :-

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.11/http.dev.js"></script>
```

for routing and http