# Difference between compiling Angular 2 typescript on server or give TS to transpiler

Tags: django, typescript, frontend, angular, django-pipeline

i just want to start with angular 2 right way. Im using django and django-pipeline. I tried pipeline typescript module, which compiling all .ts files in .js files. But i cannot run it, due errors and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34492333/angular-2-typescript-compiller-error) is my question about that, so i still not get it working!

So for now i just followed [official tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and got it running without compilation on server

So my question is, is it normal production setup to do like this, just leave all my problems to transpiler, or i need to fix my typescript compiller and files need to be JS. 
What is the right way to build project with typescript and minification + maybe obfuscation. 
Django-pipeline do all i dreamed about, but i cannot get it running with Angular, but typescript compiling ok.

Comment: I solved all my problems with angular2 webback

Answer (score 0):

I solved all my problems with angular2 webback