# angular2-google-maps unexpected token <

Tags: node.js, google-maps, typescript, angular

I have installed this with `npm install angular2-google-maps` and included it in my gulpfile like this: `'node_modules/angular2-google-maps/bundles/angular2-google-maps.js',`

so it is included but I get an `SyntaxError unexpected token<`

my map structure:

[image: Mapstructure 1]

[image: Mapstructure 2]

I saw at this: [Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34387174/angular-2-quickstart-unexpected-token)

That there is something wrong with the system.config, but I don't know how to set this right!

Here the system.config:

```
/**
 * Import angular2 components
 */
System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
    packages: {
        '/angular': {
            defaultExtension: 'ts'
        }
    }
});
System.import('/angular/main')
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Comment: This error is common when the client asks for a `.js` file but the server returns `.html` instead.

Comment: Thats exactly what it does