# Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token < SyntaxError: Unexpected token < at eval (<anonymous>) Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular, fullpage.js

I am trying to use full page with angular 2,

I am getting the below error when importing it in my app.module.ts.

```
"(SystemJS) Unexpected token <
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
        at eval (<anonymous>)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js:16:22)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js:40:4)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js:41:3)
        at eval (<anonymous>)
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-fullpage
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/main.js"
```

Below are my files:

**systemjs.config.js**

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // '@jquery':'npm:jquery/jquery.min.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'ng2-fullpage':               'npm:ng2-fullpage',
      // 'jquery':                     'npm:jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'fullpage.js':                'npm:fullpage.js/jquery.fullPage.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        // format:'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {routing} from './app.routing';
import {NavbarComponent} from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { MnFullpageDirective } from 'ng2-fullpage';
import {MnFullpageService} from 'ng2-fullpage';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { ResumeComponent } from './components/resume/resume.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './components/home/home.component';



@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,HttpModule, routing ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, ResumeComponent, AboutComponent, HomeComponent, NavbarComponent,
    MnFullpageDirective
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [MnFullpageService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Nakul Chawla</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/cyborg/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.css" />-->
    <!--<script src="node_modules/jquery/jquery.js"></script>-->

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <base href="/">
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am taking help from the npm page which reference a plunkr:

**npm package**

[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-fullpage)

http://embed.plnkr.co/1p9zKp4CNI1HncAh1h9m

**plunkr**
I have seeked help from other stack overflow pages and tried everything, but the error seems to persist.

I have posted another variation of the question on stackoverflow, both errors have the same issue.

[Unable to load ng2-fullpage in my angular-2 quickstart app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325399/unable-to-load-ng2-fullpage-in-my-angular-2-quickstart-app)

I have no clue how to resolve this, tried everything now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dunno if that's the problem, but you miss semicolon `;` at `import {HomeComponent} from './components/home/home.component'`.

Comment: @Kinduser no that's not the issue. I added and checked. I ll change the code here with the semi-colon, the issue still persists.

Comment: Okey. Use `node -v` and `npm -v` in the console and paste here the result.

Comment: @Kinduser `node -v` results in `v7.5.0` and `npm -v` results in `4.1.2`

Comment: And tell me your angular 2 version.

Comment: @Kinduser `@license Angular v2.4.8`

Comment: System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ **console.error(err);** });    This Will print Error on console Please Check that Error and try to debug or paste here.

Comment: @Swap that line already exists in my index.html file. The error that I have mentioned is the error from that function itself.

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly many issues that may lead to this error. I got it when using SystemJS in connection with web-servers such as [live-server](http://tapiov.net/live-server/) that offer a convenient function for single page web applications, namely to route all non-existing files to the index.html of the project. So if SystemJS tries to resolve a dependency that is not installed, the webserver will present the index.html that most often starts with `<!DOCTYPE html>`. This may be the unexpected `<` mentioned in the error.

### Solution:

- Check if your server routes non-existing files to an html file.
- Stop routing for the debugging.
- Launch your application. Find out using the network tab in your browser tools which files get an 404 error.
- Install missing dependencies using `jspm install my_dependency`.
- Iterate until all files can be found.
- Enable routing of missing files to some html file, again.