# angular-cli Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent Unexpected token u in JSON

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an angular 2 project using the angular-cli. I want to get a collegue setup using the project, so I have them checking out the angular-cli project and am trying to get it working on their machine.

The app starts up using 'ng serve'. However,when trying to convert json as follows:

```
let a = <any>JSON.parse(b);
```

It gives this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:3:2 caused by: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
```

The problem looks a bit similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34387174/angular-2-quickstart-unexpected-token). However, the answers all refer to system.config, whereas I am using the angular-cli.

Comment: Have you had a look in the compiled output of AppComponent? Your question includes to little information for us to help you with your problem

Comment: b is undefined. Therefore the unexpected token u(ndefined)

Comment: I am able to log b before the convert and the value is "Teacher". I have checked and the app works if I comment at the two JSON.parse lines

Comment: However, if I add an is null check then the problem is solved - perhaps it was null before. You're answer seem correct. Thank you very much for your help with this

Comment: actually, the error is still occurring

Comment: my issue that I was getting Json from local storage and it was returning: 'undefined'. I was checking to see it it was null, which also checks to see if the variable is undefined, but I need to check if it was equal to the string 'undefined'.

Comment: Glad you solved it. I was having lunch.

Comment: Thanks Hampus :)